# Crop raster files with extension in meters and degrees

Tags: r, r-raster

I need to cut a raster based on a smaller one to perform some operations, however I have a problem and it is that the extension is expressed differently in both (meters and degrees) so I cannot proceed, there is a way to solve it

he raster based on which I want to clip I got it by stacking multiple layers in a single rasterstack by resampling, I have also tried using only the resampling reference layer but it ends up with the same error

The layer that I am going to cut is the product of an RK prediction

my code below

```
Mgpred <- stack(raster("REALIZACION1_mapasrkRF.tif"))
Covs <- stack(read.RDS("covs1km")
extent(Mgpred)
#class      : Extent 
#xmin       : -14388.19 
#xmax       : 1009756 
#ymin       : 1113870 
#ymax       : 2126756 

extent(Covs)
#class      : Extent 
#xmin       : -91.04483 
#xmax       : -90.89741 
#ymin       : 14.72128 
#ymax       : 14.86761 

e <- extent(Covs)

cr <- crop(Mgpred, e)
#Error in .local(x, y, ...) : extents do not overlap
```

Comment: You have to make the projections of `Mgpred` and `Covs` the same using `projectRaster` (for raster) or `spTransform` (for vector). Without the dataset it is very hard to help you out.

Comment: it seems to me you need to reproject (`spTransform` or `st_transform`) your coordinates to the same EPSG (for example wgs84 -> epsg4326), then check if your rasters actually overlap before you start cropping. without more information/test data it is difficult to say more.